# DRF: how do I call a class inside another class method?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two separate methods:

1. to load and validate a csv file FileUploadView(APIView) [PUT]
2. to add new objects to the database based on their uploaded file data
   CsvToDatabase [POST]

**file upload**

```
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def put(self, request, format=None):
        if 'file' not in request.data:
            raise ParseError("Empty content")
        f = request.data['file']
        filename = f.name
        if filename.endswith('.csv'):
            file = default_storage.save(filename, f)
            r = csv_file_parser(file)
            status = 204
        else:
            status = 406
            r = "File format error"
        return Response(r, status=status)
```

**create instances**

```
class CsvToDatabase(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        r_data = request.data
        ...
        #some logic
        ...
            serializer = VendorsCsvSerializer(data=data)
            try:
                serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
                serializer.save()
            except ValidationError:
                return Response({"errors": (serializer.errors,)},
                                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response(request.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('csv_upload/', FileUploadView.as_view(), name='csv_upload'),
    path('from_csv_create/', CsvToDatabase.as_view(), name='csv_vendor_create'),]
```

At the moment I am simply passing manually to Postman the result of the `PUT` method of `FileUploadView` class (`Response(r, status=status`) get me json ) to POST method of `CsvToDatabase` class.
Of course, this option is not suitable for a working application. I would like to know if there is a way to call the POST method automatically inside `FileUploadView` class after the `.csv` file is processed and json is received.

I know I can transfer a `POST` method to a class `FileUploadView` and call the `self.POST` method inside the `PUT`. But combining functionality will make testing much more complicated, so I want to use different url. If that's possible, of course.

Comment: If I have a choice, I would prefer to separate the common code (the validation or other common thing) as a function and will call that function from both classes.

Comment: I have a separate .csv file parsing and validate function  `csv_file_parser` calling in `class FileUploadView`. Now I suppose it's better to call the `POST` method on the frontend side (React) after getting the successful status of `PUT` method execution.